# Angular how to call function after array loaded from service? Not concurrently

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My ionic angular app main page shows the sum of array value 'amount' using 'ionViewWillEnter'.

This works fine EXCEPT on initial load where the property 'totalExpenses' defaults to 0.

'ionViewWillEnter' is working and outputting to the console but the calculation only shows the correct result if I navigate away and back to the main page.

Why is this? I suspect getting the sum of array values is happening before the array is populated?

My .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { ExpensedataService } from "../expensedata.service";
import { Expenseitem } from "../expenseitem.model";



@Component({
  selector: "app-receipts",
  templateUrl: "./receipts.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./receipts.page.scss"],
})
export class ReceiptsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loadedExpenses: Expenseitem[];
  private expensesSub: Subscription;
  totalExpenses: number = 0;


  constructor(
    private expensedataService: ExpensedataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.expensesSub = this.expensedataService.expenseitems.subscribe(expenseitems => {
      this.loadedExpenses = expenseitems;
    });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.expensedataService.fetchExpenseitems().subscribe();
    this.calcTotal();
  }

  calcTotal() {
    let expenseTotal = 0;
    for (let i of this.loadedExpenses) {
      expenseTotal += i.amount;
     }
     this.totalExpenses = expenseTotal;
    console.log("calcTotal: " + expenseTotal);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.expensesSub) {
      this.expensesSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Could you create a stackblitz demo with the issue, please? You can fork **[this starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app?)** if you want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your funtion before the response arrives, so the loadedExpenses is empty.
Always remeber that requests are async

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.expensesSub = this.expensedataService.expenseitems.subscribe(expenseitems => {
      this.loadedExpenses = expenseitems;
      this.calcTotal(); // move to here
    });
  }
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I had acutally already tried placing the function in ngOnInIt() outside of the brackets which didn't work because as I now know it was running async!